# I want to pull Facebook posts from a public page to a Java application

Tags: java, facebook, jsoup

I am creating an app in Java that will take all the information from a public website and load it in the app for people to read using jsoup. I was trying the same kind of function with Facebook but it wasn't working the same way. Does anyone have a good idea about how I should go about this?

Thanks,
Calland

```
public String[] scrapeEvents(String... args) throws Exception {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.facebook.com/cedarstreettimes?fref=ts").get();
    Elements elements = doc.select("div._wk");
    String s = elements.toString();

    return s;
}
```

edit: I found this link of information,but I'm a little confused on how to manipulate it to get me only the content of what the specific user posts on their wall. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/graphapi/

Answer (score 2):

I had a look at the source of that page -- the thing that is tripping up the parse is that all the real content is wrapped in comments, like this:

```html
<code class="hidden_elem" id="u_0_42"><!-- <div class="fbTimelineSection ...> --></code>
```

There is JS on the page that lifts that data into the real DOM, but as jsoup doesn't execute JS it stays as comments. So before extracting the content, we need to emulate that JS and "un-hide" those elements. Here's an example to get you started:

```
String url = "https://www.facebook.com/cedarstreettimes?fref=ts";
String ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.33 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1438.7 Safari/537.33";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(ua).timeout(10*1000).get();

// move the hidden commented out html into the DOM proper:
Elements hiddenElements = doc.select("code.hidden_elem");
for (Element hidden: hiddenElements) {
    for (Node child: hidden.childNodesCopy()) {
        if (child instanceof Comment) {
            hidden.append(((Comment) child).getData()); // comment data parsed as html
        }
    }
}

Elements articles = doc.select("div[role=article]");
for (Element article: articles) {
    if (article.select("span.userContent").size() > 0) {
        String text = article.select("span.userContent").text();
        String imgUrl = article.select("div.photo img").attr("abs:src");
        System.out.println(String.format("%s\n%s\n\n", text,imgUrl));
    }
}
```

That example pulls out the article text and any photo that is associated with it.

(It's possibly better to use the FB API that this method; I wanted to show how you can emulate little bits of JS to make a scrape work properly.)

Comment: Is it possible to fetch text commented comments over a post??

Comment: is it possible to get the newlikes count from facebook page by using jsoup
for example 
https://www.facebook.com/blick/likes
from page i need new page likes count .